# segmentation fault/ not booting main from rcS

Tags: linux, c, qt, rc

I'm trying to boot a 'main' executable from the rcS file **/soft/main & 2>&1 >> /var/log/app.log &**  but I'm getting a segmentation fault witch is strange because when i cd to the application folder and type in main it works fine.

is there something i can do to figure out where the fold is and how i can fix it? 
as the only debug information in getting now is "segmentation fault"

running application on a friendly arm -> qtopia 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

the posted code has a syntax error.

There is an extra '&'

it should be:

```
 /soft/main  2>&1 >> /var/log/app.log &
```

which starts the main executable in background and re-directs both stdout and stderr to append to the app.log file

Comment: i will try this in the morning

Comment: One more error. The order should be: `>> /var/log/app.log 2>&1` Otherwise the errors go to the stout from before its redirection.